# Windows 7 installation permanently operate as the only OS?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

If I download and install Windows 7 onto my MacBook Pro, will it permanently operate as Windows, or will I be able to switch between it and OS X? I am downloading Windows 7 strictly to operate Microsoft Flight Simulator X.

Comment: You might want to consider looking into running [X-plane](http://www.x-plane.com/desktop/home/) natively on Mac OS X. I fly all the time. Virtually, that is.

Comment: The answer depends on the model/year of your Mac. I believe the 2015 or newer Macs can not run Windows 7. Also, do you intent to install the 32 bit or 64 version of Windows 7. As for switching between 0S X and Windows, this will not be a problem. Apple provides software to handle this task. Please edit your question to provide additional information. Also, what version of OS X are your currently running? Would your rather just have Windows without OS X?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, be sure to have a license for Windows 7, Windows operating systems are not "free to be used" as many Apple OSs.

Regarding your question, you can install Windows 7 in a new partition of your disk driver in order to have the possibility to choose each time you boot the machine with OS to use. There are a lot of guides online and also in this community that can help you to proceed with the installation of a dual boot.

You can also install Windows 7 on the top of the OS X you are currently using. This will remove the Apple system and you'll be able to use only the Windows one. *As a personal opinion, I don't think this is a good option (and I also think you don't want to use this option) because the MacBook Pro hardware is design to work with Apple operative system, therefore, you may have some bugs/problems when you'll use Windows. Anyway, for sure the performance of the machine will become worse.*

Another possibility, is to use a virtual machine that work under OS X and simulate the Windows machine where you can install the software you are interesting to use.
*Again as before, I don't think this is a good option knowing that the software you want to install required high performance.*